# Inplace sorting using Windows SORT Command

Tags: c#, sorting, cmd, dos

I am using Window 7's SORT command to SORT a .csv file , When i output the results to a separate csv file the command works fine but i need to do inplace sorting.

The code is below.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo= new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C sort C:\\Users\\fFayyaz\\Desktop\\12.csv > C:\\Users\\fFayyaz\\Desktop\\12.csv";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

The above code empty whole source file . If i do /C sort filename it does not sort the file. But if source and destination are different above code works perfectly.Can somebody help with inplace sorting.

Comment: Can you not sort to a temp file then copy the file over?

Comment: That would be an overhead if my files are large and they can be large .  This is what is written about GNU SORT "A sort needs to see all input before it can start to output. For this reason, the sort program can easily offer an option to modify a file in-place" , I thought same would be the case for windows but it is not , can someone possibly point out the reason why above command empty whole source file

I answered to Bob's suggestion

Comment: It empties the file because it clears it's output file before reading the input file.

Comment: Thanks Dani this is the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do in place sorting. You can simulate the effect by **renaming** the file to sort in a temp file and then launch the command to convert the renamed file into the old file name. Add dome transactionality to check if there is some error, copy back the old file with the original name.

Note : We cannot do inplace sorting and source file is empty because the command clears the output file before writing to it and as output and input files are same it looses the data

Comment: Is it sure because GNU's documentation for SORT says it can be done inplace. What possibly can be problem with doing it in windows any idea ( just curious to know ). Thanks anyways

Comment: Not to be snarky, but note that you are not running GNU SORT

Comment: Thanks Kevin but i think i know :S . btw i have figured out why window's SORT does not let us do it

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion one gets from this is that it's not possible with Windows's sort. But it is, considering that it uses a temporary file by design. So for clarification:
**sort /?**
reveals /O option to specify output file - just use the same as the input and you get your inplace sort.