# Sort BlockingCollection<IComparable> while saving to text file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a consumer that enumerates on a `BlockingCollection<T> where T : IComparable` then writes a row to a text file for each item. The end result are text files of a maximum of about 7Gb-10Gb. However they are not in order.

I cannot sort the list in memory as it could end up being very big. The only way I could think of toward a solution is to write to temp text files in order they arrive then shuffling them at the end but I can't imagine that's very efficient.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: How your text file will look like? Perhaps you could use the system's sort command.

Comment: The text file will contain 10,000's rows and each row is tab seperated with 25 'columns' per row. However each row is not a pure representation of the Class and so can not be deserialized back to the original. However the first n columns of each row are the primary key(s).

Comment: With that much data it sounds like it should just be in a database.  Is moving it there an option?  A database will have methods of sorting very large sets of data with little effort on your part.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744620/inplace-sorting-using-windows-sort-command. Perhaps a good approach is simple to write the text file as it arrives then once complete call the windows sort command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up loading the results into a staging table in SQL using SSIS and sorted them that way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe index sort if what you are looking for. The idea is to assign for each large item an index and then just sort indexes, finally just loop through ordered index array and write out files.

Wikipedia: [Memory usage patterns and index sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Memory_usage_patterns_and_index_sorting)

Comment: Reference link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659866/is-there-c-sharp-support-for-an-index-based-sort